# Japanese equivalent for "get to do something"?

Tags: verbs, expressions

I'm looking for a natural way to express that you're happy or surprised about an action. In English, "I got to spend the whole day reading", or "I get to interview him tomorrow". Does something like this expression exist in Japanese? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There is no single all-purpose phrase in Japanese that can be called the exact equivalent of "to get to" in English.

The ones that are not very wordy would include:

- 「～できる」、「～できるようになる」、「できることになる」
- 「～させてもらえる」
- 「～ていい」、「～ていいことになる」

The phrases that are wordy but still carry approximately the same meaning or nuance would include:

- 「～する / できるチャンスを得{え}る / もらう」
- 「～する許可{きょか} / 機会{きかい}を得る」

Thus, the actual sentences that use the verb phrases in your examples would be:

- 「一日中{いちにちじゅう}読書{どくしょ}できることになった。」
- 「明日Aさんにインタビューさせてもらえます。」
- 「一日中読書して（も）いいことになっている。」
- 「明日Aさんにインタビューする機会を頂{いただ}きました。」
- 「一日中読書する許可をもらっています。」